# Problema de importación con pytest

Tags: python, test, python-import

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema. Quiero realizar pruebas unitarias con pytest por tanto ejecuto `pytest test/` para realizar dichas pruebas pero esto me lanza el siguiente error de importación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no entiendo por qué ocurre esto ya que en dicho test tengo la línea `from ..knn import *`

La estructura de directorios es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan ofrecerme.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`from ..knn import *`: La sintáxis "`..`" a la hora de intentar importar un fichero del directorio padre es inválida. Esta no es la forma de proceder para importar el directorio padre.

En Python, cuando intentamos importar un módulo, el intérprete busca el fichero con dicho nombre en el directorio actual.

Si el módulo no se encuentra en el directorio actual (o en uno hijo, si se usa la sintaxis "`import directorio_hijo.nombre_fichero`"), el intérprete procede a buscar en todos los directorios añadidos al [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path), que es una `lista` que se inicializa al ejecutar el programa con todos los directorios presentes en la variable de entorno [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH):

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

[image: Ejemplo de contenido de sys.path. Obtenida de GeeksforGeeks]

Si el intérprete no es capaz de encontrar el módulo en ninguno de esos directorios, entonces la ejecución del script termina como error.

Por tanto, para poder importar un módulo que no se encuentre en el directorio actual (o en uno hijo), el directorio en el que se encuentra el módulo a importar se debe incluir en la variable `sys.path`.

Hay varias formas de hacer esto, una sencilla es añadir directamente en tiempo de ejecución el directorio a `sys.path`:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from knn import *

# ...
```

En este caso, se ha añadido el directorio padre del directorio actual usando su ruta relativa.